# Parameter 'self' unfileed:14

Tags: python-3.x, generics, pycharm

I have a problem with this error. (Parameter 'self' unfilled:14)
My code is:

```
print(' 1.Personnel\n', '2.Teacher\n', '3.Student')
person = int(input('Select a department: '))
if person == '':
    print("Empty error, try again...!")
elif person == 1:          
    personnel()
    p = Personnel
    p.show()
elif person == 2:
    print('2')
elif person == 3:
    print('3')
```

personnel() is a def in another func.
Personnel is a class in another func.

This is another error message:
TypeError: Personnel.show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I expect from this program that it gets some data by personnel function and show by method in Personnel class.

Comment: `p = Personnel()`